# Booting Linux on a PC

Tags: linux

I am new to linux. I am considering getting a Raspberry Pi and want to play around with linux to get the feel of the os. I am familiar with Unix (Max OS) and Windows but linux is new to me. Here's my question; I have successfully flashed the linux image on a micro sd card. The card uses a ScanDisc Micro Card Reader USB adapter [(Like here)](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31jGnjIvPXL.jpg) to read the SD card. My PC bios has the USB driver set as the boot disk. When the computer (PC) boots, it just hangs (black screen with a underscore flashing curser). Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Also the linux distribution I am using is "wheezy raspbian"
Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'flashed' the linux image onto to microSD card, what exactly do you mean by that?  What did you use to copy the image to the sd card?   Did you simply just copy the image (.iso) from your computer to the SD card?  pls provide more detail.

Comment: regardless of how you 'flashed' the image, i have to agree with the other posters - this is not a good way to introduce yourself to Linux.   I have been using Linux for 10 years now, and I suggest installing Virtual Box (or any virtualization software really) and grabbing a copy of Ubuntu (it is the easiest to use).   The more comfortable you get with how Linux works, then you can branch out into loading it via a SD card if you feel the need.  I can only imagine you would run into all sorts of odd technical issues trying to do what you have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, RasPi is ARM, and your computer is most likely x86 or x86_64. Look at [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) to get used to linux. It will be different looking from the RasPi OS, but its still linux, and easy to learn.

Comment: Thanks - I should have know this. I actually read it in the Raspberry Pi User Guide...

Comment: No problem, it's an easy thing to forget. As @kfmfe04 suggested in another answer, after you get used to the OS on the "live" environment, check out VirtualBox to keep changes you make without having the potential to mess up your main OS

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to experiment with Linux is to download [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install a Linux distribution on it like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

You can run Virtualbox on top of your current OS (so you don't mess up your MBR, etc...)